How to fill an iframe input using robocorp with python
I was wondering if you can help me. My question is: How can I fill an input if it is loading in an iframe?
For example, on a normal page I have this
page.fill("#id","ABCD")

But when the input is in an iframe?
Thanks in advance.
I tried something like this, but it didnt work :(
frame = page.frame_locator("iframe[id=\"__iframe3__iframe\"]")
frame.fill("#ComponentID","123456")


Finally, This works for me :)
page = browser.page()
iframe_element = page.wait_for_selector("#__loader0_iframe")
frame = iframe_element.content_frame()
frame.fill("#ComponentID","123456")
